# 8 out of 10 programmers like countdown

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, expression-building

**Edit (Jan 24/2021):** The original specification for the challenge had a few problems. Underneath the original text, I have added alternate conditions that were suggested by @caird-coinheringaahing (thanks for the tips).

There is a gameshow in the UK called "Countdown", and a parody called "8 out of 10 Cats does Countdown". One of the games in the show is called the "numbers game", and goes something like this:

- Two, three, four, five, or six "small numbers" are randomly selected. They will all be integers between 1 and 10 (inclusive). In the real game, one of the contestants will be asked to choose how many small numbers are in play; for this challenge it will have already been decided, and may be different for each input.
- Enough "big" numbers are selected such that, alongside the small numbers, there are six numbers in total. The big numbers are drawn randomly from the set `{25,50,75,100}`.
- A "target" integer is randomly selected between 100 and 999 (inclusive).

For example,
[image]

In this example there are four small numbers: 8, 8, 7, and 9. There are two big numbers: 50 and 100. The target is 690. *The presence of Jimmy Carr and/or the coveted Countdown Teapot are not part of this task.*

The players compete against each other to see who can get the closest to the target using the six numbers. The rules are:

- You can combine any subset of the numbers using addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division.
- Numbers are "atomic"; for example, `75` always means seventy-five. The `7` and `5` digits may not be used separately or be rearranged.
- No number may be used more than once.
- All intermediate values must be integers; this means division cannot be used unless the numerator is an exact multiple of the denominator, and this condition applied to all intermediate calculations.
- Note that there is no "concatenation" operator; for example, it is illegal to combine `50` and `8` to make `508`.

In the above example, one solution might be `7*100-(9+8/8)`.

## Task

Given six numbers that are randomly selected using the above method, output an expression using a subset of those numbers (with only the allowed operations) that **exactly** matches the given target number. Otherwise, produce some indication that the target is unreachable.

**Edit (Jan 24/2021):** It would be impressive if your code handles the "no solution" case in an interesting way, but this condition is **no longer necessary** for a valid solution.

## Input

The six numbers from the problem, sorted from smallest to largest, followed by the target. All numbers are separated by one ASCII space character (meaning there are 6 spaces in total).

**Edit (Jan 24 / 2021):** You may input the six numbers plus the target in any format/order that is most convenient to your program. This challenge was never supposed to be an exercise in parsing. Also, if you like, you may assume the given puzzle always has at least one solution.

#Output

If a solution exists, output a formula that, when pasted into the search bar of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), shows the target number in the "Exact Solution" output. For example:

[image]

This formula must satisfy the following properties:

- You may use any number of ASCII characters from the set `+-*/() \t\r\v\n` (duplicates allowed).
- You may use any subset of the first six numbers given in the input, written using ASCII digits.
- The formula must conform the rules of Countdown, given above.

Any formula that does not meet *all* of the above rules for valid formulas is considered to mean "No solution", and this how you can indicate that circumstance **if you choose to fulfill the extra condition of checking for "no solution".**.

Note: If your output happens to be a valid formula but it generates the wrong target, that output is considered invalid and your submission is considered null and void.

Extra brownie points if you can make Wolfram Alpha do something interesting with your output for "No solution".

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so for any valid submission, the winner is the program with the lowest byte count.

Comment: Your question is well written and specified, but as a cautionary note, it's generally recommended to post new questions in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to find duplicates and fix any possible problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a valid equation using user-specified numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6417/92901).

Comment: I would recommend removing “All numbers are separated by one ASCII space character”, and instead allowing answers to take input as a list of 6 numbers in whatever is the most convenient format (e.g. space separated, as a list/array object etc.). Also, it’s probably a better idea to allow answers to assume that the input will always have a solution, so they don’t have to worry about handling “weird” behaviour, and can focus instead on the challenge

Comment: I think I prefer this question over the older one.  The older one is less specified with some holes that I don't think are up to modern standards and only has two answers.  I think it might be better to close that as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @Razetime Okay, that sandbox would definitely have made writing this question a bit easier. Thanks to Caird for the tips; I'll make a few changed that should be "backwards-compatible" with the original.