# Make me equal to 24

Tags: code-golf, math, number, algorithm

Based on [this game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game).

## Description :

Based on Wikipedia's description.

The 24 Game is an arithmetical card game in which the objective is to find a way to manipulate four integers so that the end result is 24.
For example, for the card with the numbers **4, 7, 8, 8**, a possible solution is :

\begin{equation}
( 7 − ( 8 ÷ 8 ) ) × 4 = 24
\end{equation}

## Task :

Your job is to accept four arguments (`a, b, c, d`) and output the correct solution.

## Notes :

- All four values must be used.
- They can only be used once.
- You may only return one solution not all possibilities.
- If the given values cannot make a value of 24, output a falsey value.
- input values will be in range 1, 13 (both inclusive).

## Examples :

```
Input  : 1, 2, 3, 4
Output : (1 + 3) * (2 + 4) // --> 4 * 6 => 24
         1 * 2 * 3 * 4     // --> 2 * 12 => 24

Input  : 2, 3, 4, 5
Output : 4 * (5 + 3 - 2)   // --> 4 * 6 => 24
         (3 + 4 + 5) * 2  // --> 12 * 2 => 24

Input  : 1, 1, 1, 1
Output : false / 0 / "" / [] / ... any other falsey value

Input  : 13, 13, 6, 12
Output : 13 + (13 - (12 / 6))  // 13 + (13 - 2) ==> 13 + 11 => 24

Input  : 13, 13, 13, 13
Output : false / 0 / "" / [] / ... any other falsey value

Input  : 2, 7, 7, 13
Output : 2 * (13 - (7 / 7))  // 2 * (13 - 1) ==> 2 * 12 => 24

Input  : 7, 4, 8, 8
Output : (7 - (8 / 8)) * 4  // (7 - 1) * 4 ==> 6 

Input  : 1, 1, 10, 12 
Output : ( (1 + 1) + 10) + 12  // (2 + 10) + 12 ==> 12 + 12 => 24

Input  : 1, 2, 6, 8
Output : ( (1 / 2) * 6) * 8  // (0.5 * 6) * 8 ==> 3 * 8 => 24
```

Your solution doesn't have to match mine, you may return another possible solution :)

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins :)

Comment: This challenge is, unfortunately, a duplicate. We strongly recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) to get feedback on your challenges before posting them to the main site to avoid problems like this

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/generate-a-valid-equation-using-user-specified-numbers because any answer there can easily be copied over here with minor modifications. However, that isn't to say that this was a bad question...using the sandbox that pxeger linked to can help you make sure that your challenge isn't a duplicate, and that there aren't any problems with it.

Comment: @pxeger : will look at it. thanks :)

Comment: @lyxal : ok, thanks :)