# Compute every combination of operations written in a .TXT file

Tags: code-challenge

Your task is to create a program that computes every combination of the operations written in a .TXT file.

**Example TXT File:**

```
1
+
2
/
3
```

**Example Output:**

```
1+2/3=1
1+3/2=2
2+1/3=1
2+3/1=5
3+2/1=5
3+1/2=2
1/2+3= //See bonuses. If your program does not feature float, leave blank result.
1/3+2= //See above.
2/1+3=5
2/3+1= //See above.
3/2+1= //See above.
3/1+2=5
```

**Specs**:

- Every line of the .TXT file must contain a number **or** an operation;
- The minimum length for the .TXT file is 5 lines;
- The operations must be computed from left to right. E.g. `4+4/2` results in `4`;
- Your program should feature `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operations;
- Your program should work with any valid input of any valid length.

**Scoring:**

Code length is your starting score, but not the only parameter. Here's a short list of bonuses you can achieve to lower your score. The user with the lowest score wins.

- Implement `^`: **-20**;
- Implement `log` (in base *e*): **-30**;
- Implement `logn` (where *n* is any positive base): **-50** (only **-20** if you achieved the `log` bonus);
- Implement `e` (and the number in the line below is the exponent of 10. So `1e4`=`10000`): **-20**;
- Can handle negative values: **-10**;
- Can handle float values: **-20**;
- There are no digits (`0123456789`) in the code: **-10**;
- There is no call to `eval` or equivalent: **-20**;
- All of the above: **-100**.

For a total of **-250** bonus points.

Good luck!

Comment: Why the `The operations must be computed in order. E.g. 4+4/2 results 4;` spec? This is against the rules of math!

Comment: I was using an old calculator when I had this idea. In old calculators you had to type a number, press the desired operation, then type another number then press the desired operation again, and so on. There were no parenthesis or rules. I tried to give this challenge this behavior (also, the .TXT file is - more or less - what those calculators printed on paper :) )

Comment: That was probably put there in order to generate all possible combinations. If you allow math precedence rules, then both 4/2+4 and 4+4/2 generate the same value, and that would be pointless.

Comment: @Tobia That is indeed a nice side-effect that convinced me to post this :P With larger inputs with lots of `*` this effect is even more appreciable, like in 4*2+4*2*3!

Comment: The requirement to compute operations in order also helps further enforce the avoidance of trivial solutions which would otherwise just concatenate the TXT file and evaluate the expression. (Although those would be at a +20 disadvantage against other solutions anyway.)

Comment: Closely related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1328/194 , http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6417/194 , http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10790/194

Comment: Is the text file name a constant?  Or input?

Comment: @BenReich you decide, whichever shortens your code.

Comment: implementing `^` is extremely easy; it is just the XOR of two numbers! (If you meant power, please say so. Other people might get confused)

Comment: Rather than leaving lines blank, can we treat the numbers (like `1/2`) as `0` (ie find the greatest int less than it and use that)?

Comment: @Quincunx I really didn't think about XOR. I guess it wouldn't be fair to change the question right now :( Same applies for your other question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Mathematica (-4 = 246 - 250)

*Update:* operation `e` instead of the number representation with `e`.

*Update2:* reading from the file.

```
i = "1.txt";

w@"log"=r=Real;
e_~p~c_:=(g[x_r,w@c=c]~g~y_r:=#;p)&@e
y~Log~x~p[x+y,"+"][x-y,"-"][x/y,"/"][x*y,"*"][x*10^y,"e"][x^y,"^"]~"logn";
x_r~g~r:=Log@x
w@y_:=N@ToExpression@y
g[,x_]:=x
f@x_r:=s~Print~x
f@Fold[g,s=#<>"=";,w/@#]&/@Permutations@ReadList[i,String];
```

File:

```
1
+
2
/
3
```

Output:

```
1+2/3=1.
1+3/2=2.
1/2+3=3.5
1/3+2=2.33333
2+1/3=1.
2+3/1=5.
2/1+3=5.
2/3+1=1.66667
3+1/2=2.
3+2/1=5.
3/1+2=5.
3/2+1=2.5
```

File:

```
-1
^
2
e
3
logn
4
log
```

Output:

```
-1e2^4logn3log=2.81943
-1e2^4loglogn3=2.65196
-1e3^2logn4log=2.29916
-1e3^2loglogn4=1.89411
-1e3^4logn2log=3.68545
-1e3^4loglogn2=4.78822
-1e4^2logn3log=2.81943
-1e4^2loglogn3=2.65196
2^-1e3logn4log=1.50027
2^-1e3loglogn4=1.31783
2^-1e4logn3log=2.04804
2^-1e4loglogn3=1.94981
2^3logn4e-1log=-1.89712
2^3logn4loge-1=0.0405465
2^3loge-1logn4=-1.13287
2^3loglogn4e-1=0.0528098
2^4e-1logn3log=-0.849063
2^4e-1loglogn3=-0.687244
2^4logn3e-1log=-1.37685
2^4logn3loge-1=0.0925734
2^4loge-1logn3=-1.16766
2^4loglogn3e-1=0.0928245
2e-1logn3^4log=1.52735
2e-1log^4logn3=1.73268
2e3logn4^-1log=-1.70163
2e3logn4log^-1=0.587671
2e3log^-1logn4=-1.46309
2e3loglogn4^-1=0.683487
2e4logn3^-1log=-2.19884
2e4logn3log^-1=0.454785
2e4log^-1logn3=-2.08708
2e4loglogn3^-1=0.479139
2logn3^-1e4log=9.6709
2logn3^-1loge4=4605.61
2logn3^4e-1log=-4.14483
2logn3^4loge-1=-0.184224
2logn3e-1^4log=-11.0526
2logn3e-1log^4=58.2928
2logn3e4^-1log=-8.74978
2logn3e4log^-1=0.114289
2logn3log^-1e4=-21712.7
2logn3log^4e-1=0.00449933
2logn3loge-1^4=4.49933*10^-6
2logn3loge4^-1=-0.000217127
2logn4^-1e3log=7.6009
2logn4^-1loge3=693.147
2logn4^3e-1log=-4.38203
2logn4^3loge-1=-0.207944
2logn4e-1^3log=-8.9872
2logn4e-1log^3=-26.8849
2logn4e3^-1log=-6.21461
2logn4e3log^-1=0.160911
2logn4log^-1e3=-1442.7
2logn4log^3e-1=-0.0333025
2logn4loge-1^3=-0.000333025
2logn4loge3^-1=-0.0014427
2log^-1e3logn4=5.24728
2log^-1e4logn3=8.71723
2log^-1logn3e4=3336.14
2log^-1logn4e3=264.383
2log^3e-1logn4=-2.45411
2log^3logn4e-1=-0.079315
2log^4e-1logn3=-3.43036
2log^4logn3e-1=-0.133446
2loge-1^3logn4=-5.77604
2loge-1^4logn3=-9.71807
2loge-1logn3^4=34.8402
2loge-1logn4^3=-7.13719
2loge3^-1logn4=-4.71851
2loge3logn4^-1=0.211931
2loge4^-1logn3=-8.05
2loge4logn3^-1=0.124224
2loglogn3^-1e4=-29974.7
2loglogn3^4e-1=0.00123874
2loglogn3e-1^4=1.23874*10^-6
2loglogn3e4^-1=-0.000299747
2loglogn4^-1e3=-3782.39
2loglogn4^3e-1=-0.001848
2loglogn4e-1^3=-0.00001848
2loglogn4e3^-1=-0.00378239
3^-1e2logn4log=0.928001
3^-1e2loglogn4=0.905028
3^-1e4logn2log=2.45982
3^-1e4loglogn2=3.02001
3^2logn4e-1log=-1.84202
3^2logn4loge-1=0.0460561
3^2loge-1logn4=-1.09312
3^2loglogn4e-1=0.0567841
3^4e-1logn2log=1.10457
3^4e-1loglogn2=1.06479
3^4logn2e-1log=-0.45573
3^4logn2loge-1=0.184686
3^4loge-1logn2=-1.18625
3^4loglogn2e-1=0.213568
3e-1logn2^4log=2.20856
3e-1logn4^2log=-0.282015
3e-1log^2logn4=0.267803
3e-1log^4logn2=1.07121
3e2logn4^-1log=-1.4145
3e2logn4log^-1=0.706966
3e2log^-1logn4=-1.25596
3e2loglogn4^-1=0.796204
3e4logn2^-1log=-2.69953
3e4logn2log^-1=0.370435
3e4log^-1logn2=-3.36583
3e4loglogn2^-1=0.297104
3logn2^-1e4log=8.74978
3logn2^-1loge4=-4605.61
3logn2^4e-1log=-0.460342
3logn2^4loge-1=0.184224
3logn2e-1^4log=-7.3681
3logn2e-1log^4=11.5128
3logn2e4^-1log=-9.6709
3logn2e4log^-1=0.103403
3logn2log^-1e4=21712.7
3logn2log^4e-1=0.00449933
3logn2loge-1^4=4.49933*10^-6
3logn2loge4^-1=0.000217127
3logn4^-1e2log=4.83776
3logn4^-1loge2=23.2586
3logn4^2e-1log=-2.76776
3logn4^2loge-1=-0.0465173
3logn4e-1^2log=-5.07034
3logn4e-1log^2=6.42709
3logn4e2^-1log=-4.37258
3logn4e2log^-1=0.228698
3logn4log^-1e2=-429.948
3logn4log^2e-1=0.00540964
3logn4loge-1^2=0.000540964
3logn4loge2^-1=-0.0429948
3log^-1e2logn4=3.25409
3log^-1e4logn2=13.152
3log^-1logn2e4=-1356.82
3log^-1logn4e2=-6.78412
3log^2e-1logn4=-1.52528
3log^2logn4e-1=0.0135682
3log^4e-1logn2=-2.7792
3log^4logn2e-1=0.0542729
3loge-1^2logn4=-3.18625
3loge-1^4logn2=-12.745
3loge-1logn2^4=103.066
3loge-1logn4^2=2.53804
3loge2^-1logn4=-3.38977
3loge2logn4^-1=0.295005
3loge4^-1logn2=-13.4234
3loge4logn2^-1=0.0744968
3loglogn2^-1e4=73701.6
3loglogn2^4e-1=0.0000338917
3loglogn2e-1^4=3.38917*10^-8
3loglogn2e4^-1=0.000737016
3loglogn4^-1e2=1474.03
3loglogn4^2e-1=0.000460242
3loglogn4e-1^2=0.0000460242
3loglogn4e2^-1=0.147403
4^-1e2logn3log=1.07498
4^-1e2loglogn3=1.0641
4^-1e3logn2log=2.07516
4^-1e3loglogn2=2.46505
4^2e-1logn3log=-0.849063
4^2e-1loglogn3=-0.687244
4^2logn3e-1log=-1.37685
4^2logn3loge-1=0.0925734
4^2loge-1logn3=-1.16766
4^2loglogn3e-1=0.0928245
4^3e-1logn2log=0.985097
4^3e-1loglogn2=0.892428
4^3logn2e-1log=-0.510826
4^3logn2loge-1=0.179176
4^3loge-1logn2=-1.26573
4^3loglogn2e-1=0.20562
4e-1logn3^2log=-0.362939
4e-1log^2logn3=-0.159149
4e2logn3^-1log=-1.69629
4e2logn3log^-1=0.589523
4e2log^-1logn3=-1.62963
4e2loglogn3^-1=0.613635
4e3logn2^-1log=-2.48205
4e3logn2log^-1=0.402893
4e3log^-1logn2=-3.05208
4e3loglogn2^-1=0.327646
4logn2^-1e3log=6.21461
4logn2^-1loge3=-693.147
4logn2^3e-1log=-0.223144
4logn2^3loge-1=0.207944
4logn2e-1^3log=-4.82831
4logn2e-1log^3=-4.16891
4logn2e3^-1log=-7.6009
4logn2e3log^-1=0.131563
4logn2log^-1e3=1442.7
4logn2log^3e-1=0.0333025
4logn2loge-1^3=0.000333025
4logn2loge3^-1=0.0014427
4logn3^-1e2log=4.37258
4logn3^-1loge2=-23.2586
4logn3^2e-1log=-1.83741
4logn3^2loge-1=0.0465173
4logn3e-1^2log=-4.14
4logn3e-1log^2=4.28489
4logn3e2^-1log=-4.83776
4logn3e2log^-1=0.206707
4logn3log^-1e2=429.948
4logn3log^2e-1=0.00540964
4logn3loge-1^2=0.000540964
4logn3loge2^-1=0.0429948
4log^-1e2logn3=3.89449
4log^-1e3logn2=9.49455
4log^-1logn2e3=-471.234
4log^-1logn3e2=-29.7315
4log^2e-1logn3=-1.50127
4log^2logn3e-1=0.0594631
4log^3e-1logn2=-1.90823
4log^3logn2e-1=0.14137
4loge-1^2logn3=-3.59718
4loge-1^3logn2=-8.55208
4loge-1logn2^3=-23.1661
4loge-1logn3^2=3.23492
4loge2^-1logn3=-4.48912
4loge2logn3^-1=0.222761
4loge3^-1logn2=-10.437
4loge3logn2^-1=0.0958128
4loglogn2^-1e3=2122.09
4loglogn2^3e-1=0.0104643
4loglogn2e-1^3=0.000104643
4loglogn2e3^-1=0.00212209
4loglogn3^-1e2=336.343
4loglogn3^2e-1=0.00883964
4loglogn3e-1^2=0.000883964
4loglogn3e2^-1=0.0336343
```

Description:

- The function `w[y]` converts string `y` to the number if `y` is not an operation.
- The pattern `g[g[x,c],y]` is converted to `x+y`, `x-y`, etc depending on the operation `c`. Otherwise it stay a symbolic expression.
- `f[x]` prints `x` only if it is a number.

Comment: That doesn't appear to read from the text file. So, this doesn't complete the challenge.

Comment: @Rees Updated. Thank you for pointing me out!

Comment: You are using `ToExpression` which is the equivalent of `eval` (and you may not be evaluating `log`, only `logn`, if I'm not mistaken.) Either way, I don't think you can claim the full -250 bonus.

Comment: @Tobia `ToExpression` is the sole documented way for converting a string with one number to a number. I don't use ability `ToExpression` to convert expressions. `log` take only one argument so it is implemented separately, see `w@"log"=r=Real;` and `x_r~g~r:=Log@x` lines. I think that I implemented all bonus tasks!

Comment: Fair then. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript 21 (51 characters -10 for handling negatives -20 for handling ^)

```
"#{File.read('a.txt')}"'^'/'?'*"\n"/(20@2/{(}%+''++~
```

Explanation:

Suppose `a.txt` contains "2+3/1*4" (separated by new lines).

```
"#{File.read('a.txt')}" # Read in 'a.txt' as a string
'^'/'?'* # Replace all '^' with '?' to handle exponent.  This works by splitting the string on '^' and then folding on '?'.
"\n"/ # Split on newlines, so that we have an array of characters
(20@ # Pull out the first element of the array, push a 20 (ASCII value for space) and rearrange stack
```

At this point, the stack will look like `2 20 '+3/1*4'`.

```
2/ # Group by 2
```

So the stack looks like `2 20 [['+','3'],['/','1'],['*','4']]`.

```
{(}% # Map each element of the array to the tail of the tuple followed by its head.
```

So the stack looks like `2 20 [['3'], '+', ['1'], '/', ['4'], '*']`

```
+''++ # Concatenate, stringify, and concatenate.  Note that adding '' to an array flattens it.
```

So we are left with `'2 3 + 1 / 4 *'`.

```
~ # Finally, evaluate the string, since we were left with valid GolfScript.
```

This works with negatives, but accomplishes none of the other bonuses.

Comment: this doesn't output all possible combinations, does it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1):

#### GolfScript, score 54 (104 characters, bonus for neg., ^, e)

```
n%[[]]\{n/`{`{^2$<\@^>++}+\:^,),/}+%}/.&{2/1\{0='+-*/^e'\?0<&}/},{?}:^;{10\?*}:e;{."="+[n]@+2/{~~\~}/n}/
```

The input is given on STDIN.

**Example**

For input `1 2 3 + e`:

```
3+2e1=50
3e2+1=301
2+3e1=50
2e3+1=2001
2+1e3=3000
2e1+3=23
3+1e2=400
3e1+2=32
1+3e2=400
1e3+2=1002
1+2e3=3000
1e2+3=103
```

**Commented code with basic building blocks**

```
# split input
n%

# generate all permutations of the input (I'm working on a shorter implementation)
[[]]\{n/`{`{^2$<\@^>++}+\:^,),/}+%}/

# remove any duplicates (occur if same number/operator is given more than once)
.&

# filter for those permutations where each second element is an operator
{2/1\{0='+-*/^e'\?0<&}/},

# define operators ^ and e
{?}:^;
{10\?*}:e;

# Loop over all permutations
{
  .
  # make string representation
  "="+
  # reorder expression from ltr-infix into stack order and execute operations
  [n]@+2/{~~\~}/
  # add newline
  n
}/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript, 338 characters**

Handles `e`, negative values, and floats, bonus -50, **score 288**.

```
function g(a,p,r){a.length<1?r.push(p):a.map(function(c){g(a.filter(function(x){return x!=c}),p.concat(c),r)})}
x=[];y=[];x.push(readline());while(n=readline()){x.push(readline());y.push(n)}k=[];l=[];g(x,[],k);g(y,[],l);
l.map(function(y){k.map(function(x){r=x[0];s=r;y.map(function(b,i){n=b+x[i+1];s=s+n;r=eval(r+n);});print(s+'='+r)})})
```

Example [here](http://ideone.com/8AdvFu).

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 177 characters

- Implemented `^`: **-20**
- Handles negative values: **-10**
- No eval: **-20**

#### Total: 127

```
$<.map{|x|x=~/\d+/&&x.to_i||x.chomp}.permutation{|x|$_=x*'';a,*b=x;puts$_+"=#{b.each_slice(2).reduce(a){|m,(o,y)|[m+y,m-y,m*y,m/y,m**y]["+-*/^".index o]}}"if~/^-?\d+(\W-?\d+)*$/}
```

Run with the input file as command line argument or give input on stdin.

Chopped up for readability:

```
$<.map{|x|x=~/\d+/?x.to_i: x.chomp}
  .permutation{|x|
    $_=x*''
    a,*b=x
    puts $_+"=#{
      b.each_slice(2).reduce(a){|m,(o,y)|[m+y,m-y,m*y,m/y,m**y]["+-*/^".index o]}
    }" if ~/^-?\d+(\W-?\d+)*$/}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL, score 36

156 chars - 20 (^) - 50 (logn) - 20 (e) - 10 (negative) - 20 (float) = 36

```
{⍺←{⍵[{1≥⍴⍵:⊃,↓⍵⋄⊃⍪/⍵,∘∇¨⍵∘~¨⍵}⍳⍴⍵]}⋄e←{⍺×10*⍵}⋄⍪,(↓⍺v/⍨~d)∘.{(,⍵,⍪⍺,'='),{⍎⍕⍵,⍺}/⌽(⍎↑⍵),↓'+-×÷*⍟e'['+-*/^le'⍳∊1⌷¨⍺],⍪1↓⍵}↓⍺v/⍨d←2|⍳⍴v←('\S+'⎕S'&')⍵⎕ntie 0}
```

Without any instructions to the contrary, I made `logn` an infix operator, as you would type it on a calculator, so that log<sub>2</sub>(16) is <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>logn</kbd> <kbd>16</kbd>.

**Source**

```
⍝ main function; ⍵ is the file to read
{
    p←{1≥⍴⍵:⊃,↓⍵⋄⊃⍪/⍵,∘∇¨⍵∘~¨⍵}   ⍝ permutation matrix (taken from "dfns")
    q←{⍵[p⍳⍴⍵]}                   ⍝ all permutations of the given vector
    e←{⍺×10*⍵}                    ⍝ 'e' function as required
    v←('\S+'⎕S'&')⍵⎕ntie 0        ⍝ read input file and split on spaces
    d←2|⍳⍴v                       ⍝ bitmap of odd indices of input vector
    n←v/⍨d                        ⍝ odd-index values: the numbers
    o←v/⍨~d                       ⍝ even-index values: the operators

    ⍝ f will be called for each permutation of operators and numbers;
    ⍝ ⍺ is the (shuffled) list of operators; ⍵ of numbers
    f←{
        ⍝ translate the operators into APL
        ⍝ a trick is used to recognize 'logn' by its first letter only
        t←'+-×÷*⍟e'['+-*/^le'⍳∊1⌷¨⍺]

        ⍝ prepare the list of operations to perform, in reverse order,
        ⍝ followed by a single scalar with the value of the first number
        m←⌽(⍎↑⍵),↓t,⍪1↓⍵

        ⍝ fold over the previous vector, executing every operation in order
        r←{⍎⍕⍵,⍺}/m

        ⍝ return the result, preceded by a representation of the operation
        (,⍵,⍪⍺,'='),r
    }
    ⍝ generate all permutations of operators and of numbers; call f on
    ⍝ every combination (outer product); ravel and tabulate the result
    ⍪,(↓q o)∘.f↓q n
}
```

**Examples**

Input file:

```
-2.5
/
3
^
4
```

Output:

```
      {paste golfed code here} 'a.txt'
-2.5  /  3  ^  4 = 0.4822530863  
-2.5  /  4  ^  3 = ¯0.244140625  
3  /  -2.5  ^  4 = 2.0736        
3  /  4  ^  -2.5 = 2.052800957   
4  /  -2.5  ^  3 = ¯4.096        
4  /  3  ^  -2.5 = 0.4871392899  
-2.5  ^  3  /  4 = ¯3.90625      
-2.5  ^  4  /  3 = 13.02083333   
3  ^  -2.5  /  4 = 0.01603750748 
3  ^  4  /  -2.5 = ¯32.4         
4  ^  -2.5  /  3 = 0.01041666667 
4  ^  3  /  -2.5 = ¯25.6
```

Input file:

```
2.5
e
3
logn
4
```

Output:

```
      {paste golfed code here} 'b.txt'
2.5  e  3  logn  4 = 0.1771838201  
2.5  e  4  logn  3 = 0.1084874404  
3  e  2.5  logn  4 = 0.2022289117  
3  e  4  logn  2.5 = 0.08888300898 
4  e  2.5  logn  3 = 0.1538078748  
4  e  3  logn  2.5 = 0.1104756749  
2.5  logn  3  e  4 = 11989.77847   
2.5  logn  4  e  3 = 1512.941595   
3  logn  2.5  e  4 = 8340.437671   
3  logn  4  e  2.5 = 399.0350129   
4  logn  2.5  e  3 = 660.9640474   
4  logn  3  e  2.5 = 250.6045754
```